# Why is BigDecimal natural ordering inconsistent with equals?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

From [the Javadoc for `BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> Note: care should be exercised if `BigDecimal` objects are used as keys in a `SortedMap` or elements in a `SortedSet` since `BigDecimal`'s *natural ordering* is *inconsistent with equals*.

For example, if you create a `HashSet` and add `new BigDecimal("1.0")` and `new BigDecimal("1.00")` to it, the set will contain two elements (because the values have different scales, so are non-equal according to `equals` and `hashCode`), but if you do the same thing with a `TreeSet`, the set will contain only one element, because the values compare as equal when you use `compareTo`.

Is there any specific reason behind this inconsistency?

Comment: describe what you think is a consistent behavior: HashSet with single value or TreeSet with 2 values?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov but that's not the point of the question (even though it's an interesting question to post separately).

Comment: This is probably because you are using the String constructor. When you do that both BigDecimals now have a field that's different. I guess I don't really see what the problem is. HashSet wants the objects to be different, TreeSet wants the elements to be comparable and sortable. BigDecimal is supposed to be a number and 1.0 == 1.00. This behavior is perfectly consistent... HashSet and TreeSet are different collections.

Comment: @Radiodef just that `1.0.equals(1.00)` returns `false` but `1.0.compareTo(1.00) == 0` returns `true` (used numbers to represent two instances of `BigDecimal` storing `1.0` and `1.00` respectively).

Answer (score 8):

From the [OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/math/BigDecimal.java?av=f) of BigDecimal:

```
/**
     * Compares this {@code BigDecimal} with the specified
     * {@code Object} for equality.  Unlike {@link
     * #compareTo(BigDecimal) compareTo}, this method considers two
     * {@code BigDecimal} objects equal only if they are equal in
     * value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by
     * this method).
     *
     * @param  x {@code Object} to which this {@code BigDecimal} is 
     *         to be compared.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the specified {@code Object} is a
     *         {@code BigDecimal} whose value and scale are equal to this 
     *         {@code BigDecimal}'s.
     * @see    #compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)
     * @see    #hashCode
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x) {
        if (!(x instanceof BigDecimal))
            return false;
        BigDecimal xDec = (BigDecimal) x;
        if (x == this)
            return true;
    if (scale != xDec.scale)
        return false;
        long s = this.intCompact;
        long xs = xDec.intCompact;
        if (s != INFLATED) {
            if (xs == INFLATED)
                xs = compactValFor(xDec.intVal);
            return xs == s;
        } else if (xs != INFLATED)
            return xs == compactValFor(this.intVal);

        return this.inflate().equals(xDec.inflate());
    }
```

More from the implementation:

```
 * <p>Since the same numerical value can have different
 * representations (with different scales), the rules of arithmetic
 * and rounding must specify both the numerical result and the scale
 * used in the result's representation.
```

Which is why the implementation of `equals` takes `scale` into consideration. The constructor that takes a string as a parameter is implemented like this:

```
    public BigDecimal(String val) {
        this(val.toCharArray(), 0, val.length());
    }
```

where the third parameter will be used for the `scale` (in another constructor) which is why the strings `1.0` and `1.00` will create different BigDecimals (with different scales).

From *[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)* By Joshua Bloch:

> The final paragraph of the compareTo contract, which is a strong
>   suggestion rather than a true provision, simply states that the
>   equality test imposed by the compareTo method should generally return
>   the same results as the equals method. If this provision is obeyed,
>   the ordering imposed by the compareTo method is said to be consistent
>   with equals. If it’s violated, the ordering is said to be inconsistent
>   with equals. A class whose compareTo method imposes an order that is
>   inconsistent with equals will still work, but sorted collections
>   containing elements of the class may not obey the general contract of
>   the appropriate collection interfaces (Collection, Set, or Map). This
>   is because the general contracts for these interfaces are defined in
>   terms of the equals method, but sorted collections use the equality
>   test imposed by compareTo in place of equals. It is not a catastrophe
>   if this happens, but it’s something to be aware of.

Comment: Which educated guess are you talking about? You is even not aware of the definition of consistency: [The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Virtually all Java core classes that implement Comparable have natural orderings that are consistent with equals. One exception is BigDecimal, whose natural ordering equates BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) Please note that BigDecimal is inconsistent by definition.

Comment: @Val thanks for the link - you've got a good point even though it was phrased in a bit of a rude manner.

Comment: Why to have a question that cannot be answered to begin with?

Comment: @alfasin Do not try to present a completely wrong answer as a "wording problem".

Comment: -1 Because this doesn't answer the question, and `.equals()` doesn't "check if it's the same object" by any stretch of the imagination. In fact, `.equals()` exists *because* you want to check if two *different* objects are equal to one another. Otherwise you could just use `==`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza An objective answer exists. Unfortunately, it might be the case that it can only be provided by the designers of the language.

Comment: That quotation is really helpful and relevant. It's too bad it's prefaced by two paragraphs that are totally wrong . . .

Comment: @NullUserException The documentation for Object .equals specifically states that equals only returns true if they are the same object. It's true that not all implementations do this. Number classes and BigDecimal don't.

Comment: @Radiodef Yes, but virtually every class overrides the default implementation. I can't think of any real class where `.equals()` returns `true` if and only if they are the same object, not even interned classes like `Integer` or `String`

Comment: This seems to be true for OpenJDK and HotSpot. Can you verify if is the same for other implementations like JRockit or IBM JVM?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it has nothing to do with the JVM implementation or Java open-source community, we're discussing BigDecimal implementation.

Comment: How are you sure these JVMs use this exact implementation of `BigDecimal`? Note that HotSpot is a reference implementation, not a definitive *must-be-like-this* implementation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza JVM has nothing to do with BigDecimal implementation (Java library). You're confusing two different things.

Comment: AFAIK the core classes implementation remain inside a jar that is packaged within the JVM. In case of HotSpot, it is rt.jar. So yes, the classes implementation are JVM dependant as well. Of course, there may be JVM that uses HotSpot implementation instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The same byte-code of `BigDecimal` is loaded on any JVM implementation. JVM is just the vehicle that drives the passenger (Java libraries) so it has no relevance to our issue.

Comment: It may be a different implementation. And it may be a different byte-code for core classes implementation per JVM as well.

Comment: Good to know you have refactored code from a commercial distribution like IBM and others and verified they use the same exact implementation. I guarantee you it is not.

Comment: By the way, you may pay some read to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if you find another implementaion other than [*this one*](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/math/BigDecimal.java?av=f) let me know.

Comment: @alfasin but since they are commercial implementations, how would I review it? :)

Comment: @NullUserException that's because OpenJDK and HotSpot use the same implementation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is right. I looked at some decompiled binaries and both JRockit and IBM use different implementations of BigDecimal for their JVMs. However, one thing remains consistent: all of them take scale into consideration in the implementation of `.equals()` and will return false if the scales are different.

Comment: @NullUserException Way to go for checking the binaries of two other implementations! The BowlingBall example is also great!

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour seems reasonable in the context of arithmetic precision where trailing zeros are [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Identifying_significant_figures) and 1.0 does not carry the same meaning as 1.00. Making them unequal seems to be a reasonable choice.

However from a comparison perspective neither of the two is greater or less than the other and the Comparable interface requires a total order (i.e. each BigDecimal must be comparable with any other BigDecimal). The only reasonable option here was to define a total order such that the compareTo method would consider the two numbers equal.

Note that inconsistency between equal and compareTo is not a problem as long as it's documented. It is even sometimes [exactly what one needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534751/829571).

Comment: Most of the objects, even some primitives, are composite - and thus support different represetnations of the same value and multiple equality methods. I may find a million of cases where it is desirable even to treat identical objects as distinct. Regardless of that, Comparator interface suggests that all equality methods to be consistent. Only BigDecimal violates this recommendation. The question was WHY. You did not answer it.

Comment: @Val I think I did. My point is that 1.0 and 1.00 should not be equal when you deal with arithmetic precision. But deciding that 1.0<1.00 (or 1.0>1.00) would be arbitrary and confusing. So it makes sense that equals and compareTo are inconsistent for that reason.

Comment: Why 1.0 != 1.00 is not arbitrary and not confusing? In which arithmetic is 1 != 1? Why comparator does not use the arithmetic comparison? Any float is also made of mantissa and scale. Why don't we have inconsistency there? Do you hear that any complex object can be compared in canonical form, based on equality of every field and memory address. Comparable says that you need to normalize the object into canonical form and make the equal objects equal. Why do you need the inconsistency in case of BigDec? I do not understand why do you call arbitrary and confusing rational and self-explanatory.

Comment: 1.0 != 1.00 is typical in physics for example - 1.0 means 1 +/- 0.05 whereas 1.00 means 1 +/- 0.005. Check the link I provided. I think that it is the underlying reason for 1.0!=1.00 in BigDecimal: arithmetic precision.

Comment: I do not understand what do you want to say with the link. It tells that you may choose TreeSet comparator inconsistent with item.compareTo. Ok, it might be useful. But in case of BigDecimal we have inconsistence between BigDecimal.equals and BigDecimal.compareTo. It is a bit another type of inconsistence, which hardcoded, furthermore. So, I do not understand which flexibility/convenience you are talking about. The question is actually why do you need to "ignore the case" in case of BigDecimal?

Comment: So, the link that would be really appreciated is to support your claim that BigDecimal equality methods enforce the contract that `1.0 means 1 +/- 0.05 whereas 1.00 means 1 +/- 0.005`.

Comment: I was referring to the first link explaining how significant figures/trailing zeros work.

Comment: @Val That notion is supported by the implementation of `BigDecimal`. It uses the `scale` in the `.equals()` method, and if the scales are different, it immediately returns false.

Comment: +1 This actually makes a lot of sense. I'm very much against `1.0` being considered equal to `1.00`, and that is reflected in the `.equals()` method, but having `1.0` being arbitrarily considered "smaller" or "larger" than `1.00` would be very confusing.

Comment: Implementation stems from the notion and it is a [circular argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning) to say that it is supported by impltion. +1 It does not make any sense to say that two nums are comparabale, that they are not equal but you cannot say what is larger because they are equal. It is utter nonsense. In OOP, you may have infinitude of representations for the same value. But, comparable interface says that you should struggle to make all equality methods consistent. By demonstrating that gif != jpeg, you have failed to explain why Float does not have this problem.

Comment: @Val Not only the implementation, but the documentation for `BigDecimal.equals()` specifically states *"Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale"*. I don't see how this is a circular argument at all. The scale is definitely a factor, and this behavior is consistent in every implementation of `BigDecimal` I have looked at.

Comment: @Val That's not utter nonsense. Suppose you have a class called `BowlingBall`, where the `.equals()` method returns `true` if and only if both `BowlingBall`s have the same radius (value) and color (scale). However, `BowlingBall` also implements `Comparable`, where only the radius (value) is taken in consideration. Suppose now you have `a = BowlingBall(Color.RED, 1); b = BowlingBall(Color.BLUE, 1);`. Then `a.equals(b) == false`, but `a.compareTo(b) == 0`. It actually makes perfect sense if you look at it that way.

Comment: @Val (cont) `.equals()` may not be consistent with `.compareTo()` because they're not necessarily comparing the exact same things. For most objects, they are consistent but the introduction of a scale in `BigDecimal` makes this consistency impossible here. Bearing in mind `1.0 != 1.00` it's impossible to say which one is larger for `.compareTo()`.

Comment: @NullUserException: It would be possible for `compareTo` to regard values with more significant figures as being infinitesimally larger or infinitesimally smaller than those with fewer.  Such behavior would be consistent with `equals`.  I suspect that is not done because it is in many cases useful to be able to compare things for value equality, and when sorting with composite keys it is useful to have a loose definition of equality for the primary key [so things that are "equal" under the primary key will be sorted by the secondary key].

Comment: @supercat Sure that would be possible, but it would be completely arbitrary to say that one is "larger" or "smaller."

Answer (score 2):

BigDecimal works by having two numbers, an integer and a scale. The integer is the "number" and the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal place. Basically a base 10 floating point number.

When you say `"1.0"` and `"1.00"` these are technically different values in BigDecimal notation:

```
1.0
      integer: 10
        scale: 1
    precision: 2
             = 10 x 10 ^ -1

1.00
      integer: 100
        scale: 2
    precision: 3
             = 100 x 10 ^ -2
```

In scientific notation you wouldn't do either of those, it should be `1 x 10 ^ 0` or just `1`, but BigDecimal allows it.

In `compareTo` the scale is ignored and they are evaluated as ordinary numbers, `1 == 1`. In `equals` the integer and scale values are compared, `10 != 100` and `1 != 2`. The BigDecimal equals method ignores the `object == this` check I assume because the intention is that each BigDecimal is treated as a type of number, not like an object.

I would liken it to this:

```
// same number, different types
float floatOne = 1.0f;
double doubleOne = 1.0;

// true: 1 == 1
System.out.println( (double)floatOne == doubleOne );

// also compare a float to a double
Float boxFloat = floatOne;
Double boxDouble = doubleOne;

// false: one is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit
System.out.println( boxInt.equals(boxDouble) );

// BigDecimal should behave essentially the same way
BigDecimal bdOne1 = new BigDecimal("1.0");
BigDecimal bdOne2 = new BigDecimal("1.00");

// true: 1 == 1
System.out.println( bdOne1.compareTo(bdOne2) );

// false: 10 != 100 and 1 != 2 ensuring 2 digits != 3 digits
System.out.println( bdOne1.equals(bdOne2) );
```

Because BigDecimal allows for a specific "precision", comparing both the integer and the scale is more or less the same as comparing both the number and the precision.

Although there is a semi-caveat to that when talking about BigDecimal's precision() method which always returns 1 if the BigDecimal is 0. In this case compareTo && precision evaluates true and equals evaluates false. But `0 * 10 ^ -1` should not equal `0 * 10 ^ -2` because the former is a 2 digit number `0.0` and the latter is a 3 digit number `0.00`. The equals method is comparing both the value and the number of digits.

I suppose it is weird that BigDecimal allows trailing zeroes but this is basically necessary. Doing a mathematical operation like `"1.1" + "1.01"` requires a conversion but `"1.10" + "1.01"` doesn't.

So `compareTo` compares BigDecimals as numbers and `equals` compares BigDecimals as BigDecimals.

If the comparison is unwanted, use a List or array where this doesn't matter. HashSet and TreeSet are of course designed specifically for holding unique elements.

Comment: It makes no sense to discuss the internal representation as a reason of possible inconsistency if you claim in the end that there is no inconsistency. Learn what this question and educated people mean by inconsistency, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818537/why-is-bigdecimal-natural-ordering-inconsistent-with-equals#comment29467308_19818643. You won't be able to answer this question earlier than learn this.

Comment: @Val There is no inconsistency because TreeSet and HashSet function differently. Comparable even states it is not required that compareTo be consistent with equals. Also I hope you don't mind being disliked with your disrespectful attitude. If you are so right then why don't you write your own answer?

Comment: When comparable says that consistency is not required, it defines the meaning of `consistent`. The fact that I appreciate this definition does not mean that I know the answer. Your discovery worth a comment, as a hint. But, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Val The OP's question was why compareTo and equals return different results. I've provided an explanation for that. I've also provided an explanation for why HashSet and TreeSet are functionally different. When I used the word consistent I was referring to the fact that HashSet and TreeSet are consistent with equals and compareTo (respectively). I really have no idea what your objection is. If all you have to say are vague accusations of lack of intelligence don't leave a comment.

Comment: Your explanation is that compareTo and equals return different results. This does not answer anything as an instance of circular reasoning. For instance, I do not understand why equals was made inconsistent with compareTo. You did not answer why it was not done. You do not provide the answer. If you do not use the interpretation asked in the question, do not leave the answer. Also, you should not use circular reasoning in your argument.

Comment: @Val Your discovery *is ... Learn how educated people write, you won't be able to communicate with others *before you learn this.

Comment: @Val One looks at the numerical value and the other looks at the floating point representation. Both are useful. What's not to understand? IMO BigDecimal should discard the trailing zeroes in constructing both numbers but this is the way it works because BigDecimal is intended to utilize a specified precision. BigDecimal performs operations on the integer and scale separately so the representation is relevant because a conversion will take place. The documentation outlines how this stuff works. In a way, equals and compareTo should necessarily give different results.

Comment: @Radiodef That is [a circular argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning)

Comment: As much as I hate to agree with val (because of the "in your face" attitude he embraces), he's right. The question was not `why` the behavior is what it is, but rather why was this behavior chosen.

Comment: There is inconsistency. 0.0 is not equal to 0.00. If I am measuring says BILLIONS of people turned into zombies by a virus for example up to 99,999,999 could have died in the first example. In the second example, a maximum of 9,999,999 would have died. Precision matters.  For instance there are 0.00 trillion people on earth.

Comment: @alfasin I assume the designers thought it was useful to be able to compare both situations. I don't really see the distinction between the two questions. One method compares the number and the other effectively compares the number as well as the precision. If the question is why this behavior is chosen then I guess I would ask why does anyone think it should be different? If they should be the same, what way is the "correct" way? Personally I think both comparisons should be available and that is all there is to it. Both are available.

Comment: @Radiodef you nailed it. Asking "what way is the "correct" way?" is the million dollar question. :)

Comment: @alfasin If that is the question then that's fine and I suppose I did not answer that but the OP did not specify the distinction. Personally I think I have provided the rational behind the *why of the why* in that compareTo compares BigDecimals as numbers and equals compares BigDecimals as BigDecimals. BigDecimal allows for specified precision which means that 1.0 and 1.00 are distinct values. As I alluded to (but I guess did not state specifically), comparing *both the integer and the scale* is the same as comparing *both the number and the precision*.

Comment: @Val This is *not* an instance of circular reasoning. You keep saying that but I don't think you know what it actually means. The OP asks why there is an inconsistency between `.equals()` and `.compareTo()`. This answer explains that the inconsistency exists because of precision differences. The conclusion is not the premise; thus the reasoning is not circular.

Comment: @alfasin Both are correct and valid. They compare different things. See my bowling ball analogy under assylias's answer.

Comment: @Radiodef I'm reluctant to upvote this answer because while it touches on some good points, the analogy provided is not a very good one and trailing zeroes are not just for show. `1.0` and `1.00` are *not* the same as `1.00` has an additional [significant figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Identifying_significant_figures). When I say something weighs 1.0 grams, it could be 0.98g, or 0.97g, or 1.03g, or 1.043232423g, etc. Now if I say it's 1.00 grams  it can't be any of those (although it can still be 0.998g or 1.003g, etc.).

Comment: @NullUserException Before this question was edited, its main point was that BigDecimal has inconsistency because it is implemented this way. The bad analogy does not expose the point that it should, as you say yourself.

Comment: @NullUserException I don't think I said the trailing zeroes are for show. Most of my answer has to do with how 1.0 and 1.00 are _not_ the same number. But for purposes of comparison they are mathematically equivalent just as how float 1.0 and double 1.0 are different bit patterns but equivalent values. Also my original answer did not say what Val claims. There's nothing unusual about any of this. It is normal floating point stuff. The only thing mildly "inconsistent" is equals and compareTo are different and Comparable states it is not required they be consistent.

Comment: @NullUserException: The way in which `BigDecimal` treats trailing zeroes is inconsistent with proper scientific numerical practices.  I suspect the real reason that trailing zeroes are significant is simply that the types need to retain them for processing efficiency.  If I were designing a `BigDecimal` type, I'd use 32 bits for each group of nine decimal digits, and have the exponent represent multiples of nine digits [so 12.34 would be stored as {12, 340000000} with an exponent of 1].  Some operations would be slower in base 1,000,000,000 than in base 4,294,967,296, but...

Comment: ...decimal normalization would be *much* faster [simply scan for trailing zero words].  Further, one could perform operations like addition directly upon values with different precision, without having to adjust them to matching precision first [any trailing digits from one either get copied to the result directly, or inverted and copied].

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty short. equals() method compares objects while compareTo() compares values. In case of BigDecimal different objects can represent same value. Thats why equals() might return false, while compareTo() returns 0.

**equal objects => equal values**

**equal values =/> equal objects**

Object is just a computer representation of a some real world value. For example same picture might be represented in a GIF and JPEG formats. Thats very like BigDecimal, where same value might have distinct representations.

Comment: Most of the objects, even some primitives, are composite - and thus support different represetnations of the same value. Regardless of that, Comparator interface suggests that the equality to be consistent and only BigDecimal is made inconsistent. The question was WHY. You did not answer it.

Comment: It is suggested to be consistent, but not required. Not only BigDecimal is inconsistent, GregorianCalendar also. Have a look for more information - http://blog.joda.org/2012/11/pitfalls-of-consistent-with-equals.html

Comment: As I have told you, any object can be made inconsistent. The fact that consistency is not obligatory is a bad justification for making things inconsistent.

Comment: Second sentence of my post answers WHY. If you dont agree with it, thats another point. To be short: thees methods have different purposes.

Comment: It does not explain at all because it suggests that any object, which admits multiple representations must be inconsistent, oppositely to the design that Comparable interface prescribes. Furthermore, you may `compare objects` based on their location in memory (the default implementation of Object.equals). I do not udnerstand why you should make BigDecimal 1.0 != 1.00. Why Float methods do not have the different purposes?

Comment: *"equals() method compares objects while compareTo() compares values"* What does that even mean? How do you distinguish between the object and the value? In the case of other number types like `Integer` and `Float` why is `.equals()` consistent with `.compareTo()`? That's the heart of the question which you aren't answering.

Comment: In the last indent i tried to explain the difference between real world object and its computer representation. Sorry, if its unclear.